# Como atualizar um campo no ionic automaticamente?

Tags: ionic

Estou com problemas para gerar as coordenadas no ionic usando `geolocation`. Só funciona se ficar apertando várias vezes o botão que chama a função, até que apareçam as coordenadas. Então, eu queria saber como faço pra uma parte do código ficar chamando a função automaticamente, sem que eu fique atualizando "manualmente"?

```html
<ion-item>
          <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="cad.longitude" value="{{long}}" (click)="local()" readonly>
          </ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma função no arquivo .ts que chama a função `local()` de x em x minutos. No exemplo abaixo, chamo de 3 em 3 minutos. Esse parâmetro você estabelece na `setInterval`.

```
constructor() {


  platform.ready().then(() => {      

  setInterval(() => {
    this.local(); //sua função
  },180000);  //tempo em milisegundos


});
```

}

Comment: Deu certinho. Valeuu!

Answer (score 1):

```
var geolocationInterval;

ionViewDidLoad() {
    geolocationInterval = setInterval(() => this.local(), 5000);
}

ionViewWillLeave() {
    clearInterval(geolocationInterval);
}
```